# How can we store Kubernetes secrets in github secrets

Tags: github, kubernetes, github-actions

Hi i'm working on task that is in regards which one we should implement for Kubernets secrets Vault or github secrets.

i'm still very new to kubernets so i need help with this, if anyone can help me with some references that explain how we can store secrets and credentials in guthub secrets and use those github credentials in kubernets as secrets.

We are running

- on-prem kubernetes
- github enterprise

i have configure secrets through github and trying to use in kubernets but i have no idea how to do that just blank here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sealed Secret` to manage your k8s secrets in github.

Sealed Secrets is composed of two parts:

- A cluster-side controller / operator
- A client-side utility: `kubeseal`

The `kubeseal` utility uses asymmetric crypto to encrypt secrets that only the controller can decrypt.

To learn more, head over to [sealed-secret github repo](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets)

Comment: Thank you very much let me have look at this